# What is causing permission denied under proot?

Tags: permissions, sudo, chroot, namespace

At work I have limited access to my PC, so I am running proot with /nix mounted to give me access to nix package manager. However, executing some setuid commands fails under proot.

```
$ proot /usr/bin/crontab -e
/var/spool/cron/<name>: Permission denied
$ proot sh -c '/usr/bin/sudo --help'
sh: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

```
$ stat /usr/bin/sudo
  File: /usr/bin/sudo
  Size: 169896          Blocks: 336        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d      Inode: 872550951   Links: 1
Access: (4111/---s--x--x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-09-10 07:50:25.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2018-09-10 07:50:25.000000000 -0400
Change: 2020-06-22 17:53:31.590999394 -0400
 Birth: -
$ stat /usr/bin/crontab
  File: /usr/bin/crontab
  Size: 67592           Blocks: 136        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d      Inode: 872476679   Links: 1
Access: (4755/-rwsr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-10-31 08:36:56.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2018-10-31 08:36:56.000000000 -0400
Change: 2020-06-22 17:53:06.061999510 -0400
 Birth: -
```

*Why* does this happen? Is it possible to fix it?